# Unix memory management

Tags: unix, memory

When using top/free to see memory usage in Unix, there're 'used/free/shared/buffers/cached' categories. What do those exactly mean? I've tried to look for a wiki but didn't find detail information. Please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of that information is in the man page for top.

**Shared:** The amount of shared memory used by a task.  It simply reflects memory that could be potentially shared with other processes.
**Free**: Actually unused memory.
**Used**: Allocated to processes.
**Buffers**: Memory used for various OS buffers. Such as OS file-structures.
**Cache**: Memory used for various OS caches, generally the block and file caches.